# Calculate height of a dynamically loaded div

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay

I have a requirement where my header height changes.The header takes some time or say delay while loading.And based on the header height,my body's height has to be calculated and should be set accordingly.

Here's the sample code:

```
<div class="header header.row">
header content
</div>

<div class="main main.row">
body content
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
document.ready(function()
{
main.top=header.height;
});
```

My concern is how can we know when the header div is completely loaded.Is there any way to find that the header is finally loaded and then calculate the body position.Workaround tried is setting up delay of 750ms.But as delay normally won't work in real scenarios,trying to find alternatives.

Any help is surely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery? You can use `$(window).load(function(){});` in jQuery to get heights only after the entire page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the `onload` event, [either on `window` or `document`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371558/142240) e.g.

```
document.onload = function() {
  var height = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].clientHeight;
}
```

Note, don't need `header` and `header.row`; you should just use `header row` to give the `div` both classes.

Answer (score 0):

With **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)** it's something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.main').css('top', $('.header').height());
});
```